# C++17 class template argument deduction not working in initializer list, why?

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments

i am playing around with class template argument deduction. There is no problem creating an object of Class A in the main function, but when i try to create object of Class A in another class the deduction fails. Why?

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
    A(T value) : myValue(value) {}
 
    T myValue;
};

class B {
public:
    B(int value) : a(value) {}

    A a;    // this IS NOT working, why??
};

int main() {
    A a(100); // this IS working
    B b(100);
}
```

Comment: `A a;` doesn't have enough information to deduce the type.

Comment: So let's assume it worked. Then you add another constructor `B(std::string value) : a(value) {}` - What's the type of `a` now?

Answer (score 1):

There are very few places where placeholders may appear (see [dcl.type.class.deduct](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct)) and that's not one of them. The standard does not allow it.

The places which do allow placeholders have one thing in common: there is always an initializer. In a class, multiple constructors lead to multiple "initializers" of potentially different types. If there was consensus that placeholders in this location were desired, there would have to be a description of how to resolve the potentially different types and that takes work.